# How to display two columns(datetime and nvarchar type) with Bind() function in a repeater?

Tags: asp.net

I have an app which has this code :

```
<td scope="col">
    <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("COURT") %>'></asp:Label>
 </td>
```

I also want to show a date information with the court information. How can i combine two columns with the `Bind()` function ? I tried to combine columns in Sql,but Court is `nvarchar` and date is `DateTime`,so icouldn't do it.How can i do this in ASP.NET ? OR is there any way to combine two columns that have different types ?

Comment: wat is that u basically want to do show both columns in one td???

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("COURT") %><%#Bind("date") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Comment: i tried it but didnt work.I added two labels into the cell and used Bind function to show the informations.I couldnt find any solutions to combine Bind functions.I used two labels